# Map objects with type key & value and other different keys & values to unique components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to create a react component with the functionality described below; however, I can't seem to get the typing to work.

**Goal** Create a React component that accepts an array of objects where each object has a type key & value and keys & values for the remaining configurations. For each object in the array, the component would render the corresponding component. The intention being is that this component will be reused in multiple places with different menu items.

**Mock Implementation** *(the menu would render the components corresponding to font family and font size)*

```
<Menu
  menuItems=[
    { type: 'fontFamily', fonts: ['Arial', 'TimesNewRoman'] }, 
    { type: 'fontSize', sizes: ['12', '14'] }
  ]
/>
```

**Attempted Code Implementation** The following is my implementation of MenuItem.tsx (I omitted some items the sake of length):

```
import React from 'react'
...
import FontFamilyButton, { IFontFamilyButtonProps } from './components/FontFamilyButton'
import FontSizeButton, { IFontSizeButtonProps } from './components/FontSizeButton'
...

export type MenuItemType = 'bold' | 'italic' | 'underline' | 'fontFamily' | 'fontSize' | 'fontColor' | 'highlight' | 'customDropdown'

type PropsByMarkType = {
  ...
  fontFamily: IFontFamilyButtonProps
  fontSize: IFontSizeButtonProps
  ...
}

type MenuListMapType = {
  [key in keyof PropsByMarkType]: React.FC<PropsByMarkType[key]>
}

const markTypeToComponent: MenuListMapType = {
  ...
  fontFamily: FontFamilyButton,
  fontSize: FontSizeButton,
  ...
}

type MenuListDataType<T extends MenuItemType> = {
  type: T,
} & PropsByMarkType[T]

export default function <T extends MenuItemType>({
  type,
  ...rest
}: MenuListDataType<T>) {
  const MenuListComponent = markTypeToComponent[type]
  return <MenuListComponent {...rest} />
}
```

**Problem** However, the following error is logged at MenuListComponent:

```
Type 'Omit<MenuListDataType<T>, "type">' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<MenuListMapType[T], PropsWithChildren<PropsByMarkType[T]>>'.
  Type 'Omit<MenuListDataType<T>, "type">' is not assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes<MenuListMapType[T], PropsWithChildren<PropsByMarkType[T]>>'.ts(2322)
```

If I replace `return <MenuListComponent {...rest} />` with `return <MenuListComponent {...rest as unknown as PropsByMarkType[T]} />`, I get the following error:

```
Type 'PropsByMarkType[T]' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<MenuListMapType[T], PropsWithChildren<PropsByMarkType[T]>>'.
  Type 'IBoldButtonProps | IItalicButtonProps | IUnderlineButtonProps | IFontFamilyButtonProps | IFontSizeButtonProps | IFontColorButtonProps | IHighlightButtonProps | ICustomDropdownButtonProps' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<MenuListMapType[T], PropsWithChildren<PropsByMarkType[T]>>'.
    Type 'IBoldButtonProps' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<MenuListMapType[T], PropsWithChildren<PropsByMarkType[T]>>'.
      Type 'IBoldButtonProps' is not assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes<MenuListMapType[T], PropsWithChildren<PropsByMarkType[T]>>'.
        Type 'PropsByMarkType[T]' is not assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes<MenuListMapType[T], PropsWithChildren<PropsByMarkType[T]>>'.
          Type 'IBoldButtonProps | IItalicButtonProps | IUnderlineButtonProps | IFontFamilyButtonProps | IFontSizeButtonProps | IFontColorButtonProps | IHighlightButtonProps | ICustomDropdownButtonProps' is not assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes<MenuListMapType[T], PropsWithChildren<PropsByMarkType[T]>>'.
            Type 'IBoldButtonProps' is not assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes<MenuListMapType[T], PropsWithChildren<PropsByMarkType[T]>>'.ts(2322)
```